How can I use Powershell to check if SSE4.2 is available?
Windows 11 24H2 requires SSE4.2 support. How can I use Powershell to check if SSE4.2 is available?

Call isprocessorfeaturepresent from kernel32.dll with PF_SSE4_2_INSTRUCTIONS_AVAILABLE (38) from powershell. You can also use it to check for other cpu features like SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSE4.1, AVX or MMX.
$MethodDefinition = @"
[DllImport("kernel32")]
public static extern bool IsProcessorFeaturePresent(uint ProcessorFeature);
"@

$Kernel32 = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $MethodDefinition -Name 'Kernel32' -Namespace 'Win32' -PassThru

$featureCode = 38 # PF_SSE4_2_INSTRUCTIONS_AVAILABLE
$Kernel32::IsProcessorFeaturePresent($featureCode)

